# /boot/grub/device.map is missing on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, grub2, 14.04, certification

The device map file **/boot/grub/device.map** is in this format:

```
(disk) /dev/device
```

So, for example, on a system with a floppy and a single SCSI disk, the file would
look like this:

```
(fd0) /dev/fd0
(hd0) /dev/sda
```

I try to display its content :

```
cat /boot/grub/device.map
```

I get this error: `No such file or directory`

Is it renamed or it is a new hierarchy of Linux system?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The device map is not installed by default with grub2.  You can create a device map by typing the following into your console:

```
sudo grub-mkdevicemap
```

This will put device.map into the /boot/grub directory.

Comment: how does linux determine the hdX to sdX mapping before grub-mkdevicemap is run ?

Comment: linux uses whatever the grub boot location is in the grub.cfg 'root' property (or similar).  http://140.120.7.21/LinuxRef/BootingLinux/Grub2.html

Comment: @satch_boogie Linux does not rely on the Grub device map, as clearly shown [in the Grub manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Device-map.html). It's the other way around. Grub tries to guess the mapping that Linux chooses by itself. In fact, Linux works fine even [without Grub installed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SYSLINUX).

Comment: When I run grub-customize, it gives me an error if there's not device.map. Your solution is wonderful. And to generate grub.cfg, it's grub-mkconfig.

Comment: But I have the error that says that it's not possible to get the canonical path for /cow when trying grub-mkconfig.

Answer (score 0):

Carefully modify `/proc/sys/kernel/printk`

Set the values to the following (tabs not spaces)

```
-1  -1  -1  -1
```

This ***locks*** all kernel log levels to zero.

This really cleans up a desktop boot sequence.
Not recommended for servers which need these logs.