# How to adjust Gnu Grub TIMEOUT when Customizer fails

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I have used Grub Customizer to change the Boot Timeout to 4 seconds: Ubuntu 4.15.0-45 generic. The file has been changed but the Boot sequence always defaults to 30 seconds anyway. The 30 second delay appeared only recently before I attempted to correct the Timeout parameter. As it happens I dual boot Win10 but this makes no difference, even if I adjust the Win10 Timeout [which seems to apply to something else anyway].

The relevant file etc/default/grub is as follows:-

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="hidden"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="4"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL="console"

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID="true"

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"

GRUB_GFXMODE="640x480"
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add that this is Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. Anyway if I click on the GRUB Customizer File tab and then Change Environment I can see that there is a red Exclamation mark at the DEVICEMAP_FILE: /boot/grub/device.map. Using the answer here [/boot/grub/device.map is missing on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484042/boot-grub-device-map-is-missing-on-ubuntu-14-04#567001). I can install the relevant file - this should sort out the problem, once I have saved the configuration with GRUB Customizer.